# D straight array indexed by an enum

Tags: arrays, indexing, enums, d

In my D program, I have a read-only array of fixed length and I wish to index the array by an enumerated type.

If I do something like

```
static const my_struct_t aray[ my_enum_t ] = ... whatever ...;

my_enum_t index;

result = aray[ index ];
```

then the code produced by GDC is huge, full of calls to the runtime when the array is indexed. So it looks as if either the array is being treated as variable-length or as an associative array (hash table) or something, anyway far from a lightweight C-style array of fixed length with straightforward indexing. Since enums have a fixed cardinality and can't grow, and I have a modest sparse range of values (I'm not misusing the keyword enum just to defined a load of random constants) then I don't know why this happened.

I fixed the issue by changing the line to

```
static const my_struct_t aray[ my_enum_t.max + 1 ]
```

and as I understand it that will mean the value in the square brackets is just a known constant of integral type. Since the index is now not an enum at all, I now have an array indexed by an integer, so I have lost type checking, I could index it with any random integer typed variable rather than ensuring that only the correct (strong) type is used.

What should I be doing?

In the more general case, (silly example)

```
static const value_t aray[ bool ] = blah
```

for example, where I have an index type that is perfectly sensible semantically, but not just a typeless size_t/int/uint I presume I would get the same problem.

I wouldn't want to say that this is a compiler design problem. It's certainly a case of sub-optimal behaviour. But to be fair to the compiler what exactly is telling it whether the array is fixed-length or variable, and sparse or dense? I want two things; type checking of the index and non-variable length. Actually, in this particular case the array is const (I could have put immutable just as well) so it clearly can't be variable-length any way. But with an array that has modifiable content but is of fixed length you need to be able to declare that it is fixed-length.

Comment: The initialisation of this array is indeed done at compile-type, the declaration line has an rhs initialiser list full of known compile-time constant values.

Comment: In fact, as an example of the badness of the lack of type-checking, initially I forgot the + 1 in the square brackets, so I got the array size too small by one. Only happened to spot this by very good luck because I was looking at the generate code and saw a clue because of the name generated for the static object. I put some static asserts in because of this, but there is nothing to automate that for me.

Comment: I was thinking in Pascal (Ada?) terms.

Comment: Have done a huge amount of asm and C professionally, slowly beginning with D now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`V[K] name` is the syntax for an associative array which does indeed do runtime calls and such, even when the type is limited to a small number of values like `bool` or an enum. The compiler probably *could* optimize that, making it act to the program like an AA while implementing it as a simple fixed-length array, but it doesn't; it treats all key types the same.

I would suggest going with what you started: `T[enum.max + 1]`, but then doing a wrapper if you want to force type safety. You can make the index overloads static if you only want one instance of it:

```
enum Foo {
        one,
        two
}

struct struct_t {}

struct array {
        static private struct_t[Foo.max + 1] content;
        static struct_t opIndex(Foo idx) { return content[cast(int) idx]; }     
}

void main() {
        struct_t a = array[Foo.one];
}
```

Then, you can just genericize that if you want simpler reuse.

```
struct enum_array(Key, Value) {
        static private struct_t[Key.max + 1] content;
        static Value opIndex(Key idx) { return content[cast(int) idx]; }
}

alias array = enum_array!(Foo, struct_t);
```

Or, of course, you don't need to make it static, you could do a regular instance too, and initialize the contents inside and such.

Comment: I'll work on this basis. Many thanks. The static was there because I was making it immutable and didn't want either arrays on the stack or multiple copies of constant data.

Comment: As it happens, in this particular case, the entire thing just gets eaten up and dealt with by CTFE, so almost everything, gets just thrown away. This is because of expansion after inlining and the fact that the index values happen to always turn out to be known compile-time constants anyway. So the entire things is like a boilerplate template that maps an known enum to a known constant struct all at compile-time. Good job by the D compiler in doing CTFE.

Comment: I suppose I ought to check that the enum is not sparse, so no holes, god knows how! I also should subtract key_t.min / enum_t.min from the index (in two places) as well in the above example?

Comment: A guaranteed non-sparse enum would be nice.

Comment: Acouple of other things : Is an enum signed or unsigned? I got nasty feelings from looking at the generated code that GDC was using signed instructions occasionally (forget the exact details). I'm a very experienced asm hacker. I fixed it by using an initialiser of =0u for the first of the enum constants, that seemed to do the trick. Presumably you could have a horrible mixture of positive and negative constants in the enum. Inherited necessity from C, I suppose. But somehow, using enum for just a heap of random constants doesn't seem to do a lot.

Comment: Second minor q: I presume that a straight array index is a size_t and therefore _unsigned_, I would hope? Sanity check. Which ever way, my using enum values as an index would be a disaster if any of the values happened to be random ‘negative’ constants? Either negative offsets when indexing, or a gigantic array size. So I ought to check for that when validating the enum type.

Comment: Unfortunately a third q: can dynamic / variable-length or associative array lookups be done in CTFE? In this particular case, as I mentioned earlier, everything turned out to be solely CTFE, so it might be that I don't even need to care, it's just that my original plan frightened me to death because of all the junk code generated, whereas in fact the code needed to be kept solely as a template and never instantiated into actual generated routines just-in-case of an external caller calling a routine with a variable index.

Comment: Actually I've just answered one of my own questions thanks to Ali Çehreli. There’s an enum _base type_ thing, that’s what I need.

Comment: I realise that what  I wanted to begin with was an abstract Pascal-style enum concept. To do this properly would mean not allowing initialisation with random constants, only zero-based auto-incrementing, non-duplicated list of values, and no holes, with base type of size_t or uint only. And I would need to have a template to give me an abstract class for this, which only allowed assignment from one of the named values (strong type checking), ==, ++ and -- and its use as an index. Probably unordered too, so not even any > or < operators. Something like that.

Comment: I have gone completely off topic here - 'my dream enum' is an entirely different question.

Comment: So you kinda answered yourself, but if you set the enum base type it can also implicitly convert to it. You might just want to check  for sane conditions with `static assert` inside the thing. So like `static assert(yourenum.max < something);` and such.

Comment: And I could also check the type of the base type (somehow), to make sure it isn't signed. Checking for negative numbers might or might not fail, because they are positive and huge, but then huge is bad anyway, as we don't want sparseness and because we probably don't want multi-GB arrays popping up in that particular indexing use case.

Answer (score 1):

In D, both static and dynamic arrays are indexed by `size_t`, just like they would be in C and C++. And you can't change the type of the index in D any more than you can in C or C++. So, in D, if you put a type between the brackets in the array declaration, you're defining an associative array and not a static array. If you want a static array, you must provide an integer literal or compile-time constant, and there is no way to require that a naked, static array be indexed by an enum type that has a base type of `size_t` or a type that implicitly converts to `size_t`.

If you want to require that your static array be indexed by a type other than `size_t`, then you need to wrap it in a struct or class and control the access to the static array via the member functions. You could overload `opIndex` to take your enum type and treat your struct type as if it were a static array. So, the effect should then be effectively what you were trying to do with putting the enum type in the static array declaration, but it would be the member function that took the enum value and called the static array with it rather than doing anything to the static array itself.